# Deleting rows from DataTable takes extremely long

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `System.Data.DataTable` with about 2400 rows. I want to delete three of them but deleting takes ages - around *5 seconds* for the calls to `Delete()` and another 1.5 seconds for `AcceptChanges()`.

```cs
var dataTable = _dataSetDataGridView.Tables[tableInfo.Id];
var rowsToDelete = dataTable.Rows
                            .Cast<DataRow>()
                            .Where(row => keys.Select(v => Regex.Replace(v, @"^'|'$", "")).Contains(row[id].ToString()));

try
{
    foreach (var row in rowsToDelete)
        row.Delete();

    dataTable.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Is there anything I can do to speed up this snippet? Something **must** be wrong - it can't take that long - can it? The culprit also isn't the LINQ expression, as a trailing `ToList()` returns instantly.

Regarding the comments: @itsme86: this is why I'm extracting the rows that are to be deleted into an extra collection. I don't iterate over the original `DataTable`. But even turning the collection into a `List<DataRow>` and iterating in a `for-loop` over it doesn't change anything.

@panagiotis-kanavos: It's a WinForms application. `_dataSetDataGridView` is a `DataSet` of multiple tables which are presented in the datagrid. I had already tried to call `SuspendLayout()` on the datagridview but to no avail.

A little bit of background information: our users can change between lots of tables very easily. Some complex queries take several seconds to return data and therefore we want to load this data only once and keep it cached in the DataSet. Of course this cache **might** not always show the actual data, but this is a tradeoff we and our users are accepting. But when the user deletes data, of course she doesn't want to see it any more. The process of deleting data out of the database is done seperately and takes milliseconds as expected - it's just the presentation of the data which hits us here.

Comment: From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.delete?view=net-7.0): "Delete should not be called in a foreach loop while iterating through a DataRowCollection object. Delete modifies the state of the collection." Have you tested with turning `rowsToDelete` into a List instead of a deferred query?

Comment: What kind of applications is this and what is `_dataSetDataGridView` ? Modifying the data container a control is bound to will trigger a redraw in WinForms or WPF. One would question the usefulness of loading 2400 rows when a grid can only display eg 100 at a time, but even so, removing some rows from an *unbound* DataTable wouldn't even take a second.

Comment: If you want to filter loaded data (not actually delete rows in the database) you can create a [DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=net-7.0) from the table and bind to it. You can change the DataView's filter expression without modifying the underlying DataTable

Comment: Have you checked if the [`BeginLoadData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.beginloaddata)/[`EndLoadData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.endloaddata) methods have the desirable effect in your case?

Answer (score 2):

What happened here was that a lot of costly events were firing after each deletion. After temporarily detaching the event handlers the whole process is acceptably fast.